# Intersting Problem on Continuity

Tags: continuity

Is $ \tan^{-1}(n x)$ (tan inverse n x)is continuous at 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=\tan^{-1}(n x)\implies f'(x) = \frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}<n\\ \implies |f(x)|\le n|x|.$$
 Or

The safty way might to use the inequality 
$$|\tan x| \ge |x|$$ which is true for $|x|\le \frac{\pi}{2}$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: If we are assuming it is differentiable at 0, we are already assuming it is continuous...

Comment: You are right but still you can over com this obstacle by using this inequality $|\tan x| \ge |x|$ which is true for $|x|\le \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: I assume that has a geometric proof? That's probably the right way to go.